# Disassembly of Cpp object file: What is happening in the initialization sequence?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I have the following assembly:

```
00000000 <_main>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 e4 f0                and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   6:   83 ec 10                sub    $0x10,%esp
   9:   e8 00 00 00 00          call   e <_main+0xe>
   e:   c7 44 24 0c 04 00 00 00         movl   $0x4,0xc(%esp)
  16:   c7 44 24 08 05 00 00 00         movl   $0x5,0x8(%esp)
  1e:   8b 15 04 00 00 00       mov    0x4,%edx
  24:   8b 44 24 0c             mov    0xc(%esp),%eax
  28:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  2a:   89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
  2e:   8b 15 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0,%edx
  34:   8b 44 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%eax
  38:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
  3a:   89 04 24                mov    %eax,(%esp)
  3d:   8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
  41:   0f af 04 24             imul   (%esp),%eax
  45:   c9                      leave
  46:   c3                      ret
  47:   90                      nop
```

This is just a disassembly of an object file, so (I think) there should be no links to any operating system stuff. What does the first 9 bytes of the <_main> function mean? What is being set up here? Does it happen for every single program that runs on this type of processor (x86)?

Thanks!

Comment: First two instructions are standard stack frame, they are optional normally but here it's needed to be able to preserve `esp` and `ebp`. Third is aligning stack pointer, only required in `main` and only in case it has not already been aligned by startup code. The `sub` is allocating space for local variables, that depends on the needs of the function.

Comment: `call   e <_main+0xe>` is probably MinGW's way of getting its init functions executed before the rest of main, unless there's a function call with no args in your source.  That's not the real call target, but you disassembled a `.o` without `-r` to show relocation info, so the target address is just a placeholder, rel32=0. Many other C implementations (like GCC on GNU/Linux) either call from `_start` (which runs before `main`), or use dynamic linker hooks.

Comment: The code after the `call` suggests that it is debug build. `1e` puts 0x4 to `edx` just to add it to `0xc(%esp)`, which was initialized in `e`. So for release builds it could be way simpler, and then the part before `main` could also be simpler (by not allocating stack frame)